# Eclipse Indent Guide

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I am trying to install an indentation guide plugin for eclipse from the following web page

http://sschaef.github.io/IndentGuide/

I have not installed plugins before in eclipse and would appreciate some help.

I have downloaded the file as a .zip and extracted it. Firstly I placed the file in the plugins folder but the file was not found. I then tried placing each of the contained folders 'pdt_tools.indentGuide', 'pdt_tools.indentGuide.feature' and 'pdt_tools.indentGuide.updateSite' in the eclipse plugins folder. This time when I go to Windows>Preferences>General>Editors>Text Editors>Indent Guide, I get an error 'An error has occured when creating this preference page'.

'Unable to create the selected preference page.
jp.sourceforge.pdt_tools.indentguide.preferences.IndentGuidePreferencePage cannot be found by jp.sourceforge.pdt_tools.indentGuide_1.3.2.v20120803'

Can anyone help me install this plugin?

Answer (score 9):

Go to Help->"Install New Software" . In the window that opens you can find textbox with "type or select a site" - Enter http://sschaef.github.io/IndentGuide/update/ press enter. The Grid below should refresh , select "Indent Guide" and complete installation.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

No clue how to install from zip, but what I did was to take the "update URL" at the bottom of your link, put it into the box at the top of eclipse's help|Install New Software dialog, and install the plugin using eclipse's system. It work great for me and solves one of my major complaints with eclipse.

Comment: Worked for me also thanks. Indentation guide should definitely be standard with eclips.

Answer (score 0):

I installed it!
Step to install (Maybe it's wrong steps) But ON my STS Based on eclipse 4.4 it's working!
First:

1. Copy feature.xml from pdt_tools.indentGuide.feature into
   pdt_tools.indentGuide
2. Open build.properties at pdt_tools.indentGuide
3. Add "feature.xml" text to bin.includes = src/,\plugin.xml,\META-INF/,\OSGI-INF/ you will have:

> ```
> source.. = src/
>     output.. = bin/
>     bin.includes = feature.xml,src/,\
>                        plugin.xml,\
>                        META-INF/,\
>                        OSGI-INF/
> ```

4. Then Copy all files without ".project" from pdt_tools.indentGuide.updateSite to pdt_tools.indentGuide
5. Then go Help->Install new software->Add...->Local->(Select pdt_tools.indentGuide.updateSite) and install!

Got IT!