# IndentGuide for Eclipse OSX not working

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin

I installed IndetnGuide for Eclipse OSX so that there are visible lines int he editor.  But they aren't showing up.  Others here have referenced the same problem, but said after closing and reopening Eclipse twice, the lines showed up.  No such luck for me.  Anyone know how to get these lines to show up?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have too many tabs in Eclipse open at the same time, close all of them and reopen a tab. This should solve your problem, assuming you installed IndentGuide correctly. (if you have problem installing IntentGuide, see the best answer to this question [Eclipse Indent Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961050/eclipse-indent-guide))